# Execute some bash script before docker-compose build triggered by command

Tags: build, docker-compose

Is there a way before building of docker containers with docker compose to execute a bash script?

something like

```
version: "3"
before_script: //execute my local script 
services:
  database: ....
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No there is not.

you can make a custom bash build script that executes your local script before starting the containers

Comment: why is there no such an option????

Comment: Because the docker-compose devs say it will "break compatibility" because, for instance, Windows doesn't have `bash` by default. https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/6736